# solve matrix equations with ^(-1)

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I know matrices $A$ and $B$, whereas matrix $X$ is unknown.

Dear friend, can i do the following conversions with matrix

$(A + 2X)^{-1} = B$

$((A + 2X)^{-1})^{-1} = B^{-1}$

$A + 2X = B^{-1}$

if I'm wrong, I would like to know the right way to solve this equation, thanks

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Go on.

Comment: As long as you know that $A+2X$ and $B$ are invertible, this is fine.

Comment: Yeah, you are doing great, but be careful, you need to be sure that your matrices are invertible before aplying inverses, otherwise you will get wrong results with ''aparently'' correct arguments.